How to show the Intellij Idea external lib dependencies tree?
I am using Intellij Idea IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.5 (Community Edition) to develop a Java project, I found the dependencies spring ribbon in external libraries of the IDE. How to know the spring ribbon parent package? or show the dependencies tree. I have tried the command like this to found out the ribbon dependencies tree:

./gradlew dependencies|grep "ribbon"

there is nothing output. what should I do to show the dependencies tree. I have tried to show dependencies in IDE but seems output some useless info:

